# python '\xb4' encoding issue

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding, ascii

In python i'm not able to print the grave accent.
When i try to print it i get this exception:

```
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xb4' in file C:\Users\myuser\file.py on line 61, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

Actually in my python file i am trying to print this:

```
def graveAccent(message):
    print('`'+message+'´')
```

my question is: how can i print the grave accent? 
thanks

UPDATE:
python version is 3.7 and "message" content is "Hello"

Comment: What is your message you tried to print? Also do you use `python` 2.*??

Comment: python version is 3.7 and "message" content is "Hello"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'\xb4'` is the character you're trying to print  inside your quotations (`), it has nothing to do with your `message`, but this should only be a problem in python `2.*` and for sure not in `3.7`. Nevertheless try to add encoding on top of your code:

```
#encoding=utf-8
```

Comment: i added '#encoding=utf-8' on top of my file but the issue is still present

Comment: Tehn you need to provide more of your code because your result is not normal. I even tried it and it prints correctly.

Comment: i tried in new file and it works, but if i try to use it in my telegram bot file i get the error

Comment: thanks i solved adding simply #!/usr/local/bin/python at the top of the file